# Develop Word Add-ins in the Ribbon on Mac

Tags: ms-word, vsto, office-js, word-addins

To my understanding the only way to develop Microsoft Word Add-ins on Mac is the use the Office.js framework and develop the add-in using the taskpane. I recently ran across EndNote X9 which I was able to download on my mac and use in Word. However, EndNote pops up in the tool bar, [image]

This confused me, because I thought the only way to develop Add-ins in this format was to use VSTO, which is only compatible with Windows. Does anyone know how EndNote created this add-in for Mac?

Comment: Have you researched the Office JS APIs documentation? Since roughly Office 2016 (and any current Office 365) it's possible to define buttons and menus in the Ribbon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@CindyMeister's comment is correct. You can use the add-in's manifest to define custom ribbon tabs and buttons. The place to start in the documentation is [Add-in Commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/design/add-in-commands).